# How to return JWKS to Relying Party in OpenId Connect "jwks_uri" and How to convert RSA Public key in base64urlUInt in Java

Tags: java, openid, public-key-encryption

I am working on OpenId Connect 2.0 Discovery Endpoint. Here, we have to send URL for "jwks_uri" in Configuration Response to "Relying Party" which has the "RSA Public Key" for validating the "ID Token". I have no Idea on "How to send the RSA Public Key" I mean, In which application/json ? or some other fomat? and How to Encode the RSA Public Key in base64urlUInt in Java(Get the big-endian byte sequence of integer in Java base64urlUInt). Please Help me. Iam new to Java.
Thanks in Advance.